# Square Connect API - Is there a way to test the API without actually having my own Square merchant account?

Tags: square-connect

I'd like to test the Square Connect API before using it in an application I am creating and am wondering whether I first need to either have my own Square merchant account or have access to that of an existing Square merchant before I can proceed.

Answer (score 2):

I am testing by creating cash transactions on my merchant account from my mobile phone. Its not ideal, but its good enough to test your code.

Regards,

Prashant

Answer (score 1):

A Square account is required to use the Square Connect API at this time. However, I will pass this use case along to the API engineering team.

Comment: Any update to this one? This is somehow connected to my question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805667/is-there-any-sandbox-test-account-for-squareup