# Is there any sandbox test account for Square?

Tags: square-connect

I am trying to develop a wrapper for the Square Connect API. I am looking for a sandbox account or a way to import test data to a new account so I can get started quickly with the development side.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For future reference for people who land here from Google, Square now offers this. Every account is given a set of sandbox credentials, as well as there is an [anonymous sandbox](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/anonymous-sandbox-789459c92380) you can use without logging in.

Login here and create an application. Once you create the application, there will be Sandbox settings that you can use. 
https://connect.squareup.com/apps

Here is some more documentation:
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/using-sandbox/
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/ (general guide)

Unfortunately it doesn't seem like there is a dashboard where you can see the transactions in Sandbox mode, but I suppose it's not 100% needed.

Comment: I have same problem. My question is How can i check Sandbox transactions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Square register app on a mobile device and submit cash transactions to a live merchant account.  Not ideal, but this is what I do to add test data.

Comment: To comment, it would be nice if Square would add the facilities for an actual test account.

Comment: This would be very helpful indeed. Especially if you are developing an 3rd party application for others to use. I would like to try out the OAuth, and without creating an extra account, not sure how.