# Square API: How to generate test orders without getting charged?

Tags: square-connect

I am developing an app that uses the [Orders](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#navsection-orders) endpoint.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to place an "order" without providing a credit card.  Which means there are fees (because there is no square sandbox...)

Is there any way to test my integration without incurring fees??

Note: [This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805667/is-there-any-sandbox-test-account-for-squareup) gives a work around for the [Payments](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#get-payments) endpoint, but that is not helpful in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square has sandbox where you can use the sandbox nonce and predefined credit cards. In this way you will not get charged for the orders. Check this link https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/using-sandbox/

Comment: So glad to see a sandbox finally exists!